# MariaDB 10.0 renames foreign keys on dump insert

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb

State:
Two exact database setups with MariaDb 10.0

One is full the other empty waiting for the dump to insert.

Foreign key constraint exist on a table:

```
ALTER TABLE `rel_account_account` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Account` FOREIGN KEY (`InAccountID`) REFERENCES `t_account` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

If I dump the database by

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 livedb -r live.sql
```

and restore it on the other system by

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 livedb
mysql> SOURCE live.sql
```

Afterwards the foreign keys are renamed to a specific schema:

```
<tablename>_ifbk<index>
```

that means the FK:

```
FK_Account
```

has been renamed automatically to:

```
rel_account_account_ifbk_1
```

I did not find anything about such a possibility in the docs, so i ask this here. Is this a configurable feature, because if its done automatically i would assume that it could be very critical?

Any ideas?

EDIT: Please see answer.

Comment: I have MariaDB 10.0.15 and cannot reproduce.  My FK constraint was not renamed when importing to a new database. On your other system, do tables already exist when you run the import?

Comment: No, second is completely empty. Im on 10.0.13-MariaDB.

Comment: Did you also look in the livedb.sql file to see if the constraint name was dumped to begin with? And that it appears originally in `SHOW CREATE TABLE rel_account_account` on the source db?

Answer (score 1):

ok, seems i overwrote the dump before inserting it with another one created from NAVICAT MySql tool.

but this one, which should theoretically be the same, did not create the statements as shown by SHOW CREATE TABLE. (Thanks to @Michael Berkowski for the hint!)

I discovered that there is an option under advanced to use statements from SHOW CREATE TABLE, which does export the FK constraints with their names.

So the first dump did not set the FK names, therefor mariadb created it own key names for them, which is technically correct.

So it was a simple homemade problem, with a little technical salt.